# Synonym for "counter-trend"

Tags: single-word-requests

> In each of the years 1995, 1996, 1998, and 1999, variable X grew by 20% year-on-year. But in 1997, X fell by 50%. What might explain this *counter-trend* fall in 1997?

What might be a better word in place of "counter-trend" here? Googling "counter-trend", it seems like this is somewhat commonly used in investment, but I have not come across it anywhere else. Yet I cannot think of a better word to use in the above context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1997 results are an *[anomaly](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/anomaly)*, so you could render the last sentence as:

> What might explain this *[anomalous](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/anomalous)* fall in 1997?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the idiom *bucking the trend* in the context described.

> [bucking the trend](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/buck-the-trend) - to be obviously different from the way that a situation is developing generally, especially in connection with financial matters.

Another word that is commonly applied is *deviation*:

> To take a different course, or have a different tendency; to diverge or differ (from a standard, etc.) (OED).

Answer (score 0):

In this context "reverse" might capture your meaning better than counter-trend. You are describing a reversal of a trend, not a sub-trend that is going opposite to a simultaneous primary trend.

Comment: Yes, as George suggests, the growth from 1995-199 is a trend, what happened in 1997 only happened once, so it is not yet a trend.
You could say that the "upward trend was interrupted in 1997"